# get reciprocal best match in blast output file

Tags: python, functional-programming, biopython, blast

I'm a newbie and I'm trying to create a function that takes in two xml files and find reciprocal best matches(if a certain protein from specieA is the best match for another protein in specieB and vice versa then they are reciprocal best match) based on their total score. I hope someone can help me because I don't have a clue where to start.

```
record1=NCBIXML.parse(open(filename1))
record2=NCBIXML.parse(open(filename2))

for record in record1:
    query_id1=record.query_id

    for alignment in record.alignments:
        total_score1=0

        for hsp in alignment.hsps:
            total_score1 += hsp.bits
```

Answer (score 1):

I did this to find the orthologous genes:

- Blast A against B.
- Parse and save the best match in a dict like:

  ```
  # "A1_prot" comes from the query and "B1_prot" from the subject
  matches = {"A1_prot": "B1_prot",
             "A2_prot": "B2_prot"}
  ```
- Blast B against A.
- Parse this output while querying the previous dict with the results:

  ```
  # Now "A1_prot" comes from the subject and "B1_prot" is the query
  if matches["A1_prot"] == "B1_prot":
      orthologous.append(("A1_prot", "B1_prot"))
  ```